# How can I improve the functionality of this code

Tags: python

```
a1 = input("Enter an 8 bit  binary number to convert: ")

a1 = list(a1)

ok = False;

if a1[0] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[0] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[1] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[1] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[2] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[2] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[3] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[3] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[4] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[4] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[5] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[5] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[6] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[6] == '1':
    ok = True

if a1[7] == '0':
    ok = True

if a1[7] == '1':
    ok = True

if ok == True:
    print("Number is binary!")


n1 = 0

if a1[7] == '1':
    n1 = 1

if a1[6] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 2

if a1[5] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 4

if a1[4] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 8

if a1[3] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 16

if a1[2] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 32

if a1[1] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 64

if a1[0] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 128

print("Denary number is: " + str(n1))
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code. Do add an explanation as to what the code is supposed to do!

Comment: sorry I thought it might be obveus enough from the input at the top of the code my apologise

Comment: This looks like you are doing homework, so I made the assumption you cannot use `int()` or similar restrictions.

Comment: no, it's not homework I was just wondering about how to make the code as short and sweet as possible so when it comes to exams i have a good idea I chose this as it is most relevant to something that i could practice (binary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
a1 = input("Enter an 8 bit  binary number to convert: ")

if set(a1) <= set('01'):
    print("Number is binary!")
```

This will only be true if `set(a1)` is a subset of `set('01')`:

```
>>> set('10011') <= set('01')
True
>>> set('10011abc') <= set('01')
False
```

You can also just use exceptions (and [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to do the binary -> integer conversion):

```
try:
    n1 = int(a1, 2)
except ValueError:
    print("Not binary")
else:
    print("Number is binary")
    print("Denary number is: {}".format(n1))
```

This has the added advantage of converting your binary input to an integer in one step.

If you don't want or can use `int()`, convert back with a loop and use [`<<` left-shift](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) for each binary digit, and [`|` binary bitwise OR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) to add the new digit:

```
n1 = 0
for digit in a1:
    n1 = (n1 << 1) | (1 if digit == '1' else 0)
```

This is rather a round-about way to get the number, but at least you are using binary logic now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `all()` method in python:

```
a1 = raw_input("Enter an 8 bit  binary number to convert: ")

print all(i in ('0','1') for i in a1)
```

Comment: so would that answer any in put of binary?

Comment: @Rosco, Yes. It validates any length binary

Comment: well thank you very much then it won't let me accept you answer yet, but I will when I can thank you

Comment: @Rosco, In all fairness, Martijn's answer is much more informative and simple

Comment: ok I do agree i have just read through his i didnt understand it at first