# How can I shorten a list in python for a binary to decimal converter

Tags: python

I have a long list to solve a binary question (as input) and I don't know how to shorten it

so here is the code

```
conversion = input("Enter an 8 bit  binary number to convert: ")

conversion = list(conversion)

ok = False;

if conversion[0] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[0] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[1] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[1] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[2] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[2] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[3] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[3] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[4] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[4] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[5] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[5] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[6] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[6] == '1':
    ok = True

if conversion[7] == '0':
    ok = True

if conversion[7] == '1':
    ok = True

if ok == True:
    print("Number is binary!")


n1 = 0

if conversion[7] == '1':
    n1 = 1

if conversion[6] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 2

if conversion[5] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 4

if conversion[4] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 8

if conversion[3] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 16

if conversion[2] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 32

if conversion[1] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 64

if conversion[0] == '1':
    n1 = n1 + 128
```

Comment: Why did you repost this? We *already* addressed this before: [How can I improve the functionality of this code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24450092)

Comment: I didn't think that answer fitted my need I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = ["0","1","1","0","0","1","0","1"]

print all(x in ["0","1"] for x in my_list)
```

Comment: @Padriaic Cunningham I am not sure about the down vote however I didn't mark it as down voted besides I need 25 reputation and I only have 6 I can try your answer in just a moment thanks for trying I will get back to you soon Ross

Comment: It works well enough for what I need thank you very much thanks for the help and sorry about the down vote however i have accepted your answer thanks